# Macros in the Airflow Python operator

Tags: jinja2, airflow

Can I use macros with the PythonOperator? I tried following, but I was unable to get the macros rendered:

```
dag = DAG(
    'temp',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='temp dag',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))

def temp_def(a, b, **kwargs):
    print '{{ds}}'
    print '{{execution_date}}'
    print 'a=%s, b=%s, kwargs=%s' % (str(a), str(b), str(kwargs))

ds = '{{ ds }}'
mm = '{{ execution_date }}'

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='temp_task',
    python_callable=temp_def,
    op_args=[mm , ds],
    provide_context=False,
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Macros only get processed for templated fields. To get Jinja to process this field, extend the `PythonOperator` with your own.

```py
class MyPythonOperator(PythonOperator):
    template_fields = ('templates_dict','op_args')
```

I added `'templates_dict'` to the `template_fields` because the `PythonOperator` itself has this field templated:
[PythonOperator](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/python_operator.html)

Now you should be able to use a macro within that field:

```py
ds = '{{ ds }}'
mm = '{{ execution_date }}'

t1 = MyPythonOperator(
    task_id='temp_task',
    python_callable=temp_def,
    op_args=[mm , ds],
    provide_context=False,
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: can we mark this as the right answer? Because it is the right answer

Comment: For backward compatibility, you could overrive `template_fields` like this: `template_fields = PythonOperator.template_fields + ('op_args',)` . BTW, I opened a [JIRA to add `op_args` and `op_kwargs` to `PythonOperator` templated fields](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1814)

Comment: definitely check @cr0atIAN's answer before going this route

Comment: It looks like maybe this is now fixed and `op_kwargs` *is* templated.

Answer (score 30):

In my opinion a more native Airflow way of approaching this would be to use the included PythonOperator and use the `provide_context=True` parameter as such.

```py
t1 = MyPythonOperator(
    task_id='temp_task',
    python_callable=temp_def,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```

Now you have access to all of the macros, airflow metadata and task parameters in the `kwargs` of your callable

```py
def temp_def(**kwargs):
    print 'ds={}, execution_date={}'.format((str(kwargs['ds']), str(kwargs['execution_date']))
```

If you had some custom defined `params` associated with the task you could access those as well via `kwargs['params']`

Comment: This is probably the better way of doing it. My answer was mostly targeted at the specific question of why the macros weren't being processed.

Comment: This is the better way of doing it +1